# Returning to the normal BIOS color palette after printing a bmp in assembly

Tags: assembly, colors, x86-16, bios

I am working on a game project in 8086 assembly (in DOSBOX).

I have a working snake game that workes on graphic mode, and a menu that works on printing BMP files to the screen.

My only problem is that in the printing process i change the color palette to the bmp color palette.

**the color changing procces:**

(this is a part of the code that prints a bmp to the screen)

```
proc ReadPalette
    ; Read BMP file color palette, 256 colors * 4 bytes (400h)
    mov ah,3fh
    mov cx,400h
    mov dx,offset Palette
    int 21h
    ret
endp ReadPalette

proc CopyPal
    ; Copy the colors palette to the video memory registers
    ; The number of the first color should be sent to port 3C8h
    ; The palette is sent to port 3C9h
    mov si,offset Palette
    mov cx,256
    mov dx,3C8h
    mov al,0
    ; Copy starting color to port 3C8h
    out dx,al
    ; Copy palette itself to port 3C9h
    inc dx
    PalLoop:
        ; Note: Colors in a BMP file are saved as BGR values rather than RGB.
        mov al,[si+2] ; Get red value.
        shr al,2 ; Max. is 255, but video palette maximal
         ; value is 63. Therefore dividing by 4.
        out dx,al ; Send it.
        mov al,[si+1] ; Get green value.
        shr al,2
        out dx,al ; Send it.
        mov al,[si] ; Get blue value.
        shr al,2
        out dx,al ; Send it.
        add si,4 ; Point to next color.
        ; (There is a null chr. after every color.)
        loop PalLoop
    ret
endp CopyPal
```

**This code is not mine** and all i know is that it changes the color palette for the whole program.

When I use int 10h to print a pixel after printing an image it still is using this color palette.

But when i print a pixel before printing any image, the pixel has the normal BIOS colors.

I would like to know how to change the color palette back to the BIOS color palette.

**bmp color palette I've found:**

[image: bmp color palette I've found]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the BIOS standard palette before changing it and then store it back when done.

Sample code to do this may be

```
;WORD Buffer Segment
;WORD Buffer  Offset
;DF = Direction of saving
SavePalette:
push bp
mov bp, sp

push es
push di
push ax
push dx
push cx

mov es, WORD [bp+06h]
mov di, WORD [bp+04h]

xor al, al
mov dx, 3c7h
out dx, al      ;Read from index 0

inc dx
inc dx
mov cx, 300h        ;3x256 reads
rep insb    

pop cx
pop dx
pop ax
pop di
pop es

pop bp
ret 04h


;WORD Buffer Segment
;WORD Buffer  Offset
;DF = Direction of loading
RestorePalette:
push bp
mov bp, sp

push ds
push si
push ax
push dx
push cx

mov ds, WORD [bp+06h]
mov si, WORD [bp+04h]

xor al, al
mov dx, 3c8h
out dx, al      ;Write from index 0

inc dx
mov cx, 300h        ;3x256 writes
rep outsb       

pop cx
pop dx
pop ax
pop si
pop ds

pop bp
ret 04h
```

To use this code you need a buffer of 300h bytes, assume it is called `PaletteBuffer` and it is located in the `DS` segment.

```
push ds
push WORD PaletteBuffer
call SavePalette

;Change palette for bitmap

push ds
push WORD PaletteBuffer
call RestorePalette
```

It is worth noting that changing the whole palette is slow, consider changing the code to save/restore only the colors you need (likely the first 16) or map the bitmap colors to high index only if they are less than 256 in number.

Also this is NASM assembly and I haven't tested the code, just sketched it as I don't feel like setting a DosBox up.

Comment: did you mean `push WORD PaletteBuffer` in both calls or do I need another buffer called `PaletteSegment` ?

Comment: PaletteBuffer in both, sorry, that's a typo

Comment: @knm241 a) Both your *;3x255...* comments are wrong. Must be *;3x256...* b) When using *SavePalette* you need a 2nd `inc dx` to reach the PEL Data Register at 03C9h.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html -> inter61a.zip -> INTERRUP.A

```
--------V-101017-----------------------------
INT 10 - VIDEO - READ BLOCK OF DAC REGISTERS (VGA/MCGA)
AX = 1017h
BX = starting palette register
CX = number of palette registers to read
ES:DX -> buffer (3 * CX bytes in size) (see also AX=1012h)
Return: buffer filled with CX red, green and blue triples
SeeAlso: AX=1012h,AX=1015h,INT 62/AX=00A4h

--------V-101012-----------------------------
INT 10 - VIDEO - SET BLOCK OF DAC REGISTERS (VGA/MCGA)
AX = 1012h
BX = starting color register
CX = number of registers to set
ES:DX -> table of 3*CX bytes where each 3 byte group represents one
     byte each of red, green and blue (0-63)
Return: nothing
SeeAlso: AX=1010h,AX=1017h,INT 62/AX=00A5h
```